# Get count data from web database sitecore

Tags: sitecore

Can anyone help? How to count data from the "web" database Sitecore?

```
int count = 0;
var webDb = "web";
var rootPath = "/sitecore/content/Home";
Sitecore.Data.Database web = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(webDb);
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item dataWebDb = web.GetItem(rootPath);
return count;
```

I just tried the code above, but actually can't pass the count of items on the web database.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the total  number of items in the entire web db? Or just the items under home?

Comment: @ChrisAuer I want to get total items under home actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
int count = 0;
var webDb = "web";
var rootPath = "/sitecore/content/Home";
Sitecore.Data.Database web = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(webDb);
count = web.GetItem(rootPath).Children.Count;
return count;
```

Filter by template

```
int count = 0;
var webDb = "web";
var rootPath = "/sitecore/content/Home";
Sitecore.Data.Database web = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(webDb);
var items = web.GetItem(rootPath).Children.Where(x => x.TemplateID == new ID("{54a1e38d-a052-40bc-b767-def8bcd7e19b}"));

return items.Count;
```

Comment: But, I have a question. Can we get those items that with the template listed in the solr config?

Comment: Can you help for my question?